# How to create a c++ class (.h and .cpp) in android studio?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-studio-2.3

I am learning to use the android NDK and try to create a native c++ class (.h and .cpp). I followed the official tutorial (https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) to achieve this. I managed to create a simple c++ class and call it from java, no problem.

Now I want to create my own c++ class (let's say a HellowWorld class) with just a constructor that does nothing. to do this, I right click on my cpp folder which contain my already working JNI wrapper.

I create my class and create a default constructor and call it from my JNI function but it crashed during the compilation:

> Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.

  > Build command failed.
  >   Error while executing 'C:\Users\lucien.moor\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {--build C:\Users\lucien.moor\Desktop\tmp\MyApplication2\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\mips64 --target native-lib}
  >   [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
  >   [2/2] Linking CXX shared library ........\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\mips64\libnative-lib.so
  >   FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\lucien.moor\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=mips64el-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/lucien.moor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/lucien.moor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-mips64 -fPIC -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o ........\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\mips64\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  -llog -lm "C:/Users/lucien.moor/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/mips64/libgnustl_static.a" && cd ."
  >   CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o: In function `Java_he_1arc_myapplication2_MainActivity_stringFromJNI':
  >   C:\Users\lucien.moor\Desktop\tmp\MyApplication2\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:10: undefined reference to`HelloWorld::HelloWorld()'
  >   clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  >   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I think there is a problem while linking the .h and .cpp file. When I try to implement my constructor inline, it works fine. it just doesn't find the .cpp implementation.

Here is my JNI native-lib.cpp file :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

extern "C"
jstring
Java_he_1arc_myapplication2_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
JNIEnv *env,
jobject /* this */) {
HelloWorld t;
std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

here is my Helloworld.h:

```
#ifndef MYAPPLICATION2_HELLOWORLD_H
#define MYAPPLICATION2_HELLOWORLD_H


class HelloWorld {
public:
     HelloWorld();
};
#endif //MYAPPLICATION2_HELLOWORLD_H
```

and here is my HelloWorld.cpp

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"
HelloWorld::HelloWorld() { }
```

when I open this file, android studio tells me ***"This file is not part of the project. Please include it in the appropriate build file (build.gradle, CMakeLists.txt or Android.mk etc.) and sync the project."***

so, how do I link these lovely .h and .cpp together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution!

as the message suggested, I had to add my file inside CMakeLists.txt. Headers file is not required but .cpp file has to be added in the CMakeLists.txt

To allow the linker to find the implementation file, I hust had to add

```
src/main/cpp/HelloWorld.cpp in my CMakeLists.txt
```

Here is the full CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         native-lib

         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED

         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         # Associated headers in the same location as their source
         # file are automatically included.
         src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
         src/main/cpp/HelloWorld.cpp)
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
          log-lib

          # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
          # you want CMake to locate.
          log )
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-lib
                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Weird to need to add every new class to CKMakeLists

Answer (score 0):

```
public:
 HelloWorld();
```

That should at least be

```
public:
 HelloWorld()
   {
   //......
   }
```

Comment: It works but this is not what I want to achieve, I want the implementation to be inside the CPP file. The final goal is to use already written C++ classes (splitted in .h/.cpp) and I don't want to modify them. And I also think that doing the declaration and implementation is not a good practice in c++

Comment: Sorry i thought that it came from your .cpp file. Well then leave the .h unchanged and put this in a .cpp file.

Comment: This is what I do with HelloWorld::HelloWorld() { } but the compiler says it doesn't find the implementation. It's like the HelloWorld.cpp is not part of the project and the compiler doesn't find it

Comment: No not the compiler. That can only come from a linker. Check if it gets compiled first by typing some nonsense in the cpp file. You then should get compiler errors.

Comment: yes the linker fail :

    `clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to 
    see invocation) 
    `ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

It also says : 

`C:\Users\lucien.moor\Desktop\tmp\MyApplication2\app\src\main\cpp/native-lib.cpp:10: undefined reference toHelloWorld::HelloWorld()'

Comment: Is native-lib.cpp your cpp file? Or how did you call that file? "HelloWorld.cpp" ?

Comment: native-lib.cpp is my JNI wrapper. You can see his content in the question.

Comment: `"This file is not part of the project. Please include it in the appropriate build file`. Do not try to compile it. Concentrate on this message. You confused me by trying to compile.

Comment: I tried to add the file inside the CMakeList but I didn't manage to make it work. I have no clue how to tell Android studio that this file is part of the project. Do you have any tips?